# yii 1.1 select2 jquery conflict with yii jquery

Tags: netbeans, drop-down-menu, yii, jquery-select2, conflict

I am working on a project in yii, in which i am using jquery select2 extension, I have created a searchable dropdown list using select2 extension in `localhost/business/package/create` page, now when i want to create a package the drop down list just becomes drop down, not searchable, unless i remove this line from my layout `<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/jquery.js"></script>`. After that i can create the package,with my seachable drop down list, but my rest of the pages are not scrolling. If i open the view source of `package/create` these files are already added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/businessadvisor/assets/f81f8ab/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/businessadvisor/assets/1075462/select2.js"></script>
```

so the crux is a because of a single file, my rest of the pages are not scrolling, nor clicking etc. so what is the solution to deal with this conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You are including jQuery multiple times, so the second inclusion will overwrite all the already included plugins.

You can use the `scriptMap` option to specify the location of jQuery for the whole site.

```
'components'=>array(

...
'clientScript'=>array (
    'scriptMap'=>array(   
        'jquery.js'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js',
    ),
    ...
),
...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the answer. The problem was, when i commented out `<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/jquery.js"></script>` from my admin.php (my layout), drop down in `package/create`start working, while the rest of the pages becomes stuck, not scrolling nor clicking. so one file was creating a whole problem, to solve this, you need to go into your `custom.js`and replace `$` with `jQuery` and save it. Now I had below files under my footer widget.

```
<!-- <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/jquery.js"></script>-->

        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/slimmenu.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/nicescroll.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/dropit.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/ionrangeslider.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/icheck.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/fotorama.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/typeahead.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/card-payment.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/magnific.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/owl-carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/fitvids.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/tweet.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/countdown.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/gridrotator.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/custom.js"></script>
```

I commented out `<!-- <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/jquery.js"></script>-->`jquery and in header of my layout having these files

```
<head>
    <title>Business Advisor,Where you give ratings and reviews</title>


    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Template, html, premium, themeforest" />
    <meta name="description" content="Traveler - Premium template for travel companies">
    <meta name="author" content="Tsoy">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- /GOOGLE FONTS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/icomoon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/mystyles.css">
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/modernizr.js"></script>

</head>
```

so what i did, i copied this code

```
<?php
    $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
    $cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');?> <!-- put these files in admin.php so that conflcit will resolve from select2 extension select2.php-->
```

from my `select2.php` and paste in my header like this.

```
<head>
    <title>Business Advisor,Where you give ratings and reviews</title>


    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Template, html, premium, themeforest" />
    <meta name="description" content="Traveler - Premium template for travel companies">
    <meta name="author" content="Tsoy">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- /GOOGLE FONTS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/icomoon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/mystyles.css">
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<?php
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');?> <!-- put these files in admin.php so that conflcit will resolve from select2 extension select2.php-->

</head>
```

Now the jquery has been registered. and now my every page, even `package/create`
is working, every thing is scrolling, no conflict at all. Cheers :)